# Running geth - ssh doesn't work

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

The Ethereum light node is synced by geth, but when we tried to sync it we lost ssh connection. We assumed that while it is syncing it is impossible to connect via ssh to computer. If anyone has any idea why this should happen. We also have the most ports closed. The open ports are just ssh, http and one more. This problem happens just in one computer, at other is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

How have you established that SSH disconnection depends on your operation of Geth ?

SSH and Geth can both be configured to bind to specific ports.  Confirm which those are, and confirm that your SSH connection requests reaching the computer.